# Can I use virt-install for the new Ubuntu installer?

Tags: virtualization

What I have understood so far, it's possible to use PXE mode(?) with the Ubuntu installer.

Is it still possible to use virt-install?

In the [documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-virt-tools), they refer to an installation using `-c` switch which does not allow though headless walk-through configuration for the installer.

If using as previously with bionic the switch `--location`, the ISO seems to miss important components.

`virt-install` command (virt-install version 1.5.0):

```
virt-install --wait -1 --force --debug --noreboot --name ubuntu-20.04-00123456 \
             --noautoconsole --graphics vnc \
             --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu-20.04-114046.qcow2,format=qcow2,size=10,bus=scsi \
             --controller type=scsi \
             --location $OS_ISO \
             --os-type=linux --os-variant ubuntu18.04 -r 2048 --vcpus=2 --network network=default \
             --features acpi=on,apic=on --initrd-inject config/20.04/preseed.cfg -x edd-off -x ipv6.disable=1
```

Error:

```
[virt-install 44526] ERROR (cli:318) Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
[virt-install 44526] DEBUG (cli:320)
```

Comment: as far as i know, yes. i have used it to install multiple server VM's and one desktop VM. see also [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-virt-tools) (and actually, the example virt-install command is the one I used while testing.

Comment: @DougSmythies thank you: possibly I have a more complex requirement either/or just obsolete virt-install.

Comment: My host was a 20.04 server with `virt-install` version `2.2.1`.

Comment: Hi, I think he's using the server installer which no more has the kernel/initrd unpacked in a subdir. There is a bug for that to provide a new path that makes these reachable. Currently ongoing for s390x, maybe chime in there to make sure it is done cross arch. But also this is another time to recommend to NOT use installers for VMs, there just is no need - cloud-images are so much more suited for that via multipass or uvtool-kvm for example.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt thank you for your comment - please confirm: due to to a backward compatibility, bug, currently it's not possible to install a KVM machine locally other than for s390x hardware architecture?
Regarding "no need" - what would be the alternative which is less obsolete for an Apache CloudStack template? (because the cloud images are for public clouds, right?)

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt what I don't understand, is that using the --cdrom option the installation works for me. So in that case there is no boot process required?

Comment: @J.Doe - the difference between --location/--cdrom all comes down to oddities in virt-install (which I don't like very much anyway). For --location it tries to fetch kernel/initrd while with cdrom it just boots the ISO. The man page has more on this. But more importantly cloud-images are really NOT just for public clouds. For a much more modern way to do "spawn from image it and customize it" see https://ubuntu.com/blog/using-cloud-init-with-multipass please (not sure how that aligns with cloudstack templates as I never used them)

Comment: I defer to @ChristianEhrhardt for this. He is a subject matter expert, I am not. I like and use virt-install and simply have no desire to try some other method. I only chimed in to say it had worked for me (for a desktop VM install also, whatever installer that uses).